# Printing a block of elements in a list

Tags: python

Is there a good way to print n elements of a list, for example 10, after that the next 10 numbers?

```
    liste = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    for i in range(0,len(liste),10):
        for j in range(10):
        print(liste[j])
```

This just prints the numbers from 1-10 and begins at 1 again.

I want something like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

bassically cut the list into parts of n elements the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [python list slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/):

```py
your_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

for i in range(0, len(your_list), 10):
    chunk = your_list[i:i+10]
    print(','.join(list(map(str,chunk))))
```

Outputs:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

---

Related links:

[How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Does exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @Emanuel, glad that it's solved. And if my answer is helpful, could you please help accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: @RithinChalumuri `join()` is a string method. This fails when you run it with the given list with `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`.

Comment: It will work if you change the print to `print(','.join(list(map(str,your_list[i:i+10]))))` to convert the ints to str before the join.

Comment: @DavidBuck, thanks for pointing out I typed this on the go without testing, so I will update the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `j` runs from 0 to 9 on every iteration.

Try `print(liste[i*10+j])`.